# "MainMenu Designer" em Runtime

Tags: delphi, menu

Em modo de designer é muito fácil montar o menu principal de uma aplicação com Delphi, e sei também montar um menu via código em tempo de Execução.
Mas o que estou querendo fazer é possibilitar ao usuário final trabalhar no menu por meio do "**MainMenu Designer**" que acessamos facilmente no Delphi em *designer* ao darmos dois cliques sobre o componente `TMainMenu`.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

É possível fazer o acima? Como?

Segue o objetivo que desejo atingir:
Todos os menus estão ligados a um mesmo evento, que chama uma função que abre um formulário de acordo com uns parâmetros recebidos. O menu principal do sistema é montado dinamicamente, com base nos dados de uma tabela do banco de dados. O que gostaria é de facilitar a manutenção nessa tabela do bd.

Comment: Olá, Trabalho com Dephi à quase 7 anos e até hoje nunca vi cliente trabalhando com o TMainMenu.

Comment: Se o que eu entendi é: Cliente adicionar ou remover Menus "Existentes e ja programados" é facil. Mas se a intenção for desenvolver um novo menu, exemplo, adicionar um "Sobre" que não esta programado e que tenha algum efeito é "impossível"!

Comment: @JúniorMoreira Todos os menus estão ligados a um mesmo evento, que chama uma função que abre um formulário de acordo com uns parâmetros recebidos. O menu principal do sistema é montado dinamicamente, com base nos dados de uma tabela do banco de dados. O que gostaria é de facilitar a manutenção nessa tabela do bd.

Comment: Edite a pergunta e adicione detalhes deste código